# Create and program a button that will delete the last letter in uitextview

Tags: swift

I want to make a button, in my app, to delete the last letter on a uitextview,for example if uitextview = "Good" if the button is pressed it should be "Goo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have started to use **Swift 2**, then place the following line in the method called when you press the button (remember to change "theTextView" to the name of your @IBOutlet)

```
theTextView.text = String(theTextView.text.characters.dropLast())
```

If you are still using **Swift 1**, then this line of code does the same thing:

```
theTextView.text = dropLast(theTextView.text)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need .. BTW I still use Swift 1 .. ;)